# Installing PgBouncer on a Dokku instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dokku

I have an app currently on a 48GB (12 vCPU) DO server, which is struggling with connection sizes. We have an API that gets hit ever 5 minutes by 350~ IoT devices and it gets added to a background queue for log processing.

I have tried using both delayed_job and sidekiq for background processing, however both create so many database connections that it exceeds the postgresql default 100 connection limit and causes downtime. I have had to temporarily remove this background processing. Without the background processing, we use around 60-65 postgresql connections.

- I am running Dokku `0.6.5`
- Postgresql was installed using this [dokku plugin](https://github.com/Flink/dokku-psql-single-container)
- App is Ruby on
  Rails
- My database.yml pool size is set to 5, my puma worker threads are 5 so I followed herokus recommendation that these should match.t

I am not conclusive in how PgBouncer can be installed on a dokku app that is running postgresql through a plugin. Currently, my only idea is to upgrade my dokku to `0.15.0`, which then has buildpack support and I can install the [heroku PgBouncer buildpack](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-pgbouncer).

I would greatly appreciate any insight on the best way to install PgBouncer with this set-up.